# Removing XCode while keeping the command line tools (on El Capitan)

Tags: command-line, xcode

As by subject.  There are a number of links, such as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38198/how-to-uninstall-xcode-ide-without-completely-removing-the-dev-tools) that deal with the issue but are not El Capitan specific and/or are just not that on the subject or are not up to date.

Is it possible to Uninstall XCode 7 while keeping the Command Line Tools (and still being able to get the CLT upgrades)? Should I just uninstall everything and reinstall just the CLT (how?)?

Any other way?

Answer (score 28):

Personally, I think that instead of trying to "[bodge](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bodge)" a method of uninstalling Xcode while leaving CLT intact is too cumbersome.  My suggestion is to:

1. Uninstall Xcode completely
2. Install Xcode CLT

Doing this should take you less than 5 minutes total and is quite simple.

---

### Uninstall Xcode

There are a number of different ways to uninstall Xcode.  An excellent tutorial can be found at [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/).

However, the most reliable way I have found to uninstall software is with the *free* app recommended by [Macworld.com](https://www.macworld.com/article/2995495/operating-systems/remove-extra-application-files-with-appcleaner.html) called [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).  You can "drag and drop" or "Search" for your apps that you want to remove and it will find all related files/directories for you - even the ones that get installed as launch daemons.

*Disclaimer:  I am **not** affiliated with the app or the developers of the app in any way.*

### Install Xcode CLT (Yosemite through Sierra)

Installing Xcode CLT is actually quite simple.  In Terminal, execute the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

You will get a dialog box that will prompt you to "Get Xcode," "Cancel," or "Install."  Select "Install" to install the CLT *only*.

[image: xcode-select install dialog]

The installer will do its thing and will notify you once it's complete.  Once finished, you will have access to tools such as `git` and `svn`.  You can execute those commands by testing them out in Terminal.

CLT will be installed to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

That's it!  Xcode CLT are installed and ready for use.

Comment: I did exactly how you suggested. Xcode is removed while `brew doctor` for example gives me `Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool`and `xcode-select --install` returns `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: Did you delete the `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`?

Comment: No, as not indicated in your procedure. Going to.

Comment: Sometimes with AppCleaner, you have to select the folders - it's not perfect, but it's really good.

Comment: Yes, it's a good app and I was already using it. I deleted the CLT folder and reinstalled but the problem with brew remains (brew is the only reason I need CLT, I do not use Xcode anymore and it occupies ~9GB)

Comment: So you installed CLT - does that work?  Now brew (I don't use brew) is throwing an error?

Comment: Yes, before removing Xcode, brew was working fine

Comment: You may need to reinstall brew **or** create symlinks from the commands to `/usr/bin/`

Comment: Also svn was not working. To fix I had to run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

Comment: I think you should update your answer.

Comment: I tried this method on Sierra, actually AppCleaner won't delete the command line tool folder, and you don't need to. Just delete all files found by AppCleaner, then do `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`. Run `brew doctor` to make sure everything is OK.

Comment: Small update: `brew doctor` doesn't return any errors in my system: deleting with AppCleaner was enough.

Answer (score 0):

### Monterey: uninstall Xcode, re-install CLI tools

**Update**: I just upgraded my MacBook Air to Monterey (took ages) then used Homebrew to install the apps I use. Running `brew doctor` warned of outdated Xcode. Read up, realised I only need Xcode to develop Apple apps (which I don’t do) but need the CLI tools. Did the following after reading through this and many other posts:

1. `brew install --cask appcleaner` (I've used AppCleaner many times before)
2. remove Xcode by dragging the Xcode app from Applications to AppCleaner and deleting all finds in one go via AppCleaner
3. run `brew doctor`, which highlighted that there were now no CLI tools
4. followed Homebrew message to `xcode-select --install`

All fine, thanks to some of the advice above.