# Traces of Visual Studio for mac throughout macOS!

Tags: mac, macos, microsoft

I recently installed Visual Studio For Mac.  I didn't liked the IDE and UI so I removed it, according to steps suggested by various stack exchange community posts.

Today when I used Omni Disk Sweeper to sweep my Main Disk, I came across the files shown in the screenshot.  Visual studio was the only application I have ever downloaded from Microsoft.  Can these files be related to Visual Studio?

If they are VS-related, how can I remove them (and other traces of Visual Studio)?

[image]

Comment: Relevant (and similar) answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/243506/119271 - Use [AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove, open Terminal and run

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/share/dotnet
```

Comment: I was thinking of removing it but it also contains files which don't seem to be connected to visual I have already screwed my mac once I don't want to screw it again I also ran this script but nothing got removed  [link] https://pastebin.com/89PNW1Ah

Comment: @Sayan The Pastbin script doesn‘t touch the dotnet directory at all